# Translation of "too good to be true"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

In English, we say something is "too good to be true" to express that apparently amazing deals or benefits generally aren't real. Is there an equivalent phrase in Spanish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The literal translation of it is the common way of saying that:

> **Demasiado bueno para ser verdad**

also you could say something like:

> **Demasiado bueno para ser cierto**

Also there is a proverb for that kind of situations which says (thanks leonbloy and Icarus):

> **Cuando la limosna es grande hasta el santo desconfía** (used at least in Mexico)
>
> **De eso tan bueno no dan tanto** (used at least in Colombia)

Comment: +1 For once, the literal translation works. And in this context, there is also a popular saying that might be used (but not as translation) "Cuando la limosna es grande hasta el santo desconfía" .

Comment: @leonbloy Where is that proverb typical from? I've never heard it in Spain.

Comment: I thought it was traditional... at least it's also popular in Mexico http://www.almallanera.org/refranes.htm

Comment: "De eso tan bueno no dan tanto" is also used in Colombia.

Comment: @leonbloy thanks, I've updated it's used in Mexico :)